# autosize font in quarto presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, powerpoint, pandoc, quarto

Am I able to set font in a Quarto presentation to auto-size to the text window object of the slide? I am starting to build a talk to show everyone at my company how great `{quarto}` is, but am dreading the task of `render --> check font size --> adjust font --> check again` for each window on each slide to make sure my text does not spill over off the viewable area.

PowerPoint does this automatically when you type text into a field.

Example `quarto-pptx-resize-text.qmd` below, for reference the `template.pptx` referenced is the default rendered pptx with a wordmark for my company added to the master slide(s).

```
---
title: "quarto-pptx-resize-text"
author: "M. Wood"
format: 
    pptx: 
        reference-doc: template.pptx
---

## A Few Lines (4)

- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog

## A LOT of Lines (20)

- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
- the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

---

[image: title slide]

---

[image: A Few Lines slide]

---

[image: A Lot of Lines slide]

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share an examle of an overlowing text so the problem can be reproduced?

Comment: Hi @user12256545 , you're right... I should try to make a tiny reprex here to illustrate the point. Will post that up in a few mins.

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with PowerPoint?  If not, you might want to remove that tag.

Comment: I wasn’t sure at the time I posted @SteveRindsberg. Are we sure the issue is exclusive to one of the other tags? My understanding is that there’s some interaction between the PPTX format and either quarto or pandoc.

Comment: The PPTX format being what it is, if some other combination of programs makes the wrong thing happen, the PPTX format is sort of a non-issue. But if you want to leave the tag there, I'm not going to complain.